# Replicate Element-wise in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

Let's say, I have:
`A=[1 2; 3 4];`

I want to use repmat that return:

```
B = [1 1 2 2; 1 1 2 2; 3 3 4 4; 3 3 4 4]
```

Kindly need your help. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know a method using `repmat` but here is a method using `kron`

```
kron([1 2 ; 3 4],[1 1;1 1])

ans =

 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which uses `repmat` is

```
A=[1 2; 3 4];
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)repmat(x,2,2),A,'UniformOutput',false))

ans =

 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4
```

`arrayfun` is used to evaluate each element in `A` using the anonymous function `@(x)repmat(x,2,2)` which replicates that single element into a 2x2 matrix.

The result of `arrayfun` is a 2x2 cell array where each element is a 2x2 matrix.  We then convert this cell array into a matrix via `cell2mat`.

Answer (score 0):

Let the data be defined as

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
R = 2; %// number of repetitions of each row
C = 2; %// number of repetitions of each column. May be different from R
```

Two possible approaches are as follows:

1. The simplest method is to use indexing:

   ```
   B = A(ceil(1/R:1/R:size(A,1)), ceil(1/C:1/C:size(A,2)));
   ```
2. If you really want to do it with `repmat`, you need to play with dimensions using `permute` and `reshape`: move original dimensions 1, 2 to dimensions 2, 4 (`permute`); do the repetition along new dimensions 1, 3 (`repmat`); collapse dimensions 1, 2 into one dimension and 3, 4 into another dimension (`reshape`):

   ```
   [r c] = size(A);
   B = reshape(repmat(permute(A, [3 1 4 2]), [R 1 C 1]), [r*R c*C]);
   ```

Example result for `R=2`, `C=3` (obtained with any of the two approaches):

```
B =
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
```